# Android app 'Update' not showing on play store

Tags: android, google-play, apk, release, publish

I have released (production) my app on google play store. The first version code and version name was 1.0 and "1.0" accordingly. but when I try to update the app by releasing the 2.0 version I can't see the 'Update' option on end users android phone on play store page. The end users have to uninstall and install the app again.

I have printed the app version in my app. It shows version 1.0 and on play store page it shows next version (2.0), still I cant see the 'Update' button.

My question is how to resolve this issue, Please guide me.

Comment: Can you try on multiple devices ? Looks like some device specific issue.

Comment: I have tried this on atleast 3 devices. None of them showing the 'Update' button on play store app page.

Comment: Can you tell me which all devices you have tested on ?

Comment: Moto G5 Plus , Redmi Note , Moto X play , Lenovo A3600

Comment: Guys help out plz, this is the first ever apk i have launched for the client.

Comment: Try contacting them here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9042516?visit_id=636776025824778935-4189160345&hl=en&rd=2

Comment: This will help you and make your client very happy
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55939853/how-to-work-with-androids-in-app-update-api