# Android: Cannot find method updatePriority() in class AppUpdateInfo

Tags: android, in-app-update

I implement in-app update follow document:
https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates#check-priority

I want to check update priority, but I can't find the updatePriority() method in the AppUpdateInfo class.
Did they remove that method?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/56060453/7626390

Comment: It seems they haven't implemented updatePriority() method. I found some advice on using Firebase Remote Config.