# Force Update Apk - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to create an AlertDialog that always forces the user to update the app and always use the current one

But when putting this code it does not appear, even the trial version is inferior to the one from the Google Play store

Google Play: 
versionCode: 6 
versionName "1.6"

Test: 
versionCode 4
versionName "1.4"

Below is the code used:

```
@Override
 public void onStart() {
     super.onStart();
     UpdateApp();
 }




    public void UpdateApp() {
        AppUpdateManager appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(this);
        Task<AppUpdateInfo> appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo();

        appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener(result -> {

            if (result.updateAvailability() != UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE ){

                android.view.ContextThemeWrapper ctw = new android.view.ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.AlertDialog_AppCompat_Light);
                final android.app.AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(ctw);
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("NOVA VERSAO");
                alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
                alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Uma nova atualizacao esta disponivel na loja, realize atualizacao do mesmo para ter uma melhor experiencia");
                alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("ATUALIZAR", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        try {
                            startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.glam33.dpms&hl=pt-BR")));
                        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                            startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.glam33.dpms&hl=pt-BR")));
                        }
                    }
                });
                alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("CANCELAR", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


                    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        finishAffinity();
                    }
                });
                alertDialogBuilder.show();

            } else {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: To work with AppUpdateManager you need to create a release variant build. I hope you are trying your changes with it only

Comment: sorry but could you give me an example

Comment: Sure. I assume you have not set up an internal app-sharing option. Please do that first and later follow the steps given here https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates/test#internal-app-sharing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55939853/how-to-work-with-androids-in-app-update-api this will be of help as well